Intellij Plugin - add line breaks after components in ToolWindow
In Intellij's UI lib, I have a bunch of form fields that I want to add with line breaks after them - right now if I resize the tool window to be wider than a certain amount the fields show the labels after the previous field. I'll attach to screen shots showing narrow (looks OK) and wide (does not look OK) - how can I force line breaks so that when I extend the window it does not drag the components up onto the same line as the previous.
Generally, their examples suck and the guidelines tell you to put things on separate lines but they don't show you how...
Code:
            add(JBLabel("URL"))
            add(JBTextField(24))

            add(JBLabel("Client ID"))
            add(JBTextField(24))

            add(JBLabel("Client secret"))
            add(JBTextField(24))

            add(JBLabel("Refresh token"))
            add(JBTextField(24))

Looks OK on narrow panel:

Looks bad on wide panel:


See if it helps to ask at the official JetBrains plugin development forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development
